# black screen, no errors (OpenGL, C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

So I have been trying to write a basic program that displays a quad on the screen.
And no matter what I do it just shows a black screen.
I checked the libraries, everything was linked.
I checked the code, everything seemed fine (but I know that its not)
but most absurdly: when I paste a what seems like the same program into the same project on the same computer it works, and when I paste the one again, it does not work, again.

By the way - I also tried running it through a text difference finder online... it showed that it was the same thing.

Original code (not working):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

static unsigned int CompileShader(const std::string& source, unsigned int type) {
    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    // i - int
    // v - vector
    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        std::cout << "Shader cannot be compiled.\n" << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex s." : "fragments.") << "\n";
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)_malloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << message << "\n";
        glDeleteShader(shader);
    }
    return shader;
}
static int CreateShader(const std::string& vShader, const std::string& fShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(vShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(fShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
    return program;
}
int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "CITY ENGINE", 0, 0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();
    float vertices[8] = { 0.1f, 0.1f,
    -0.1f, 0.1f,
    -0.1f, -0.1f,
    0.1f, -0.1f };
    unsigned int varray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &varray);
    glBindVertexArray(varray);
    unsigned int vbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(vbuffer, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 2 * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    unsigned int indices[6] = { 0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0 };
    unsigned int ibuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibuffer);
    glBindBuffer(ibuffer, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position = position;\n"
        "};\n"
        ,
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "uniform vec4 u_Color;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   color = u_Color;\n"
        "};\n"
    );
    glUseProgram(shader);
    int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_Color");
    glUniform4f(location, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glBindBuffer(0, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(0, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(varray);
        glBindBuffer(ibuffer, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        glUseProgram(shader);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

The working one:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

static unsigned int CompileShader(const std::string& source, unsigned int type) {
    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    // i - int
    // v - vector
    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        std::cout << "Shader cannot be compiled.\n" << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex s." : "fragments.") << "\n";
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)_malloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << message << "\n";
        glDeleteShader(shader);
    }
    return shader;
}
static int CreateShader(const std::string& vShader, const std::string& fShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(vShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(fShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
    return program;
}
int main() {
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Modern OpenGL Test", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,
         -0.5f,  0.5f,
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };
    unsigned int varray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &varray);
    glBindVertexArray(varray);
    unsigned int vb;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vb);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 2 * sizeof(float), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    unsigned int ib;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ib);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    unsigned int shaders = CreateShader(
     "#version 330 core\n"
     "\n"
     "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
     "\n"
     "void main()\n"
     "{\n"
     "   gl_Position = position;\n"
     "};\n"
        ,
     "#version 330 core\n"
     "\n"
     "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
     "\n"
     "uniform vec4 u_Color;\n"
     "\n"
     "void main()\n"
     "{\n"
     "  color = u_Color;\n"
     "};\n");
    glUseProgram(shaders);
    int location = glGetUniformLocation(shaders, "u_Color");
    glUniform4f(location, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(varray);
        glUseProgram(shaders);
        glBindBuffer(ib, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glDeleteProgram(shaders);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad++ compare returns 2 significant differences between your files.

1. `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);` -> `glBindBuffer(vbuffer, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);`
2. `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib);` -> `glBindBuffer(ibuffer, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER);`

And quick look at [docs.gl](http://docs.gl) tells me that first argument should be `target` and not `buffer`

Comment: thanks... totally forgot about the docs :)